# Error while opening office dialogue api

Tags: office-js

I am getting below error while calling dialog api,Please suggest

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerForEvent' of null
    at OSF.DDA.WAC.Delegate.registerEventAsync (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:108641)
    at e.(anonymous function) (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:70644)
    at Object.value [as addHandlerAsync] (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:77346)
    at r.initializeAndChangeOnce (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:210348)
    at OSF.InitializationHelper.prepareRightBeforeWebExtensionInitialize (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:241143)
    at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js:12:12892
    at d (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/Office.js:12:3420)

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'invoke' of null
    at Object.OSF.DDA.WAC.Delegate.executeAsync (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:107319)
    at e.(anonymous function) (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:69419)
    at Object.n.(anonymous function).OSF.OUtil.defineEnumerableProperty.value [as executeRichApiRequestAsync] (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:77000)
    at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:287255
    at Promise ()
    at t.executeAsync (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:287195)
    at i.syncPrivate (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:255809)
    at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:21:255150
    at

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This console error will impact dialog api functionality. And the error has already been resolved in Prod environment. You can clear your cache and try again to check whether it is still exist. Thank you !